# Можжевельник — от какого слова?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Интересно, слово "можжевельник" происходит от слова "разможжить" или слова просто похожи?

Comment: Нет такого слова "разможжить". Правильно будет РАЗМОЗЖИТЬ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По мнению Фасмера, слово **можжевельник** связано со словом *мозг*, т. е. "с ядреной, крепкой древесиной". Некоторые исследователи сближают это слово с лит. ma~zgas "узел" и считают исходным знач. "узловатое дерево".

В Историко-этимологическом словаре П.Я.Черных о слове **можжевельник** говорится, что оно сложное, состоит из двух основ (для сранения: в латинском juniperus 'можжевельник' тоже сложное слово). Вторую основу автор связывает с *ель, ельник* (у Даля встречается областное название можжевельника - *еленец*; ср. словацк. borovka - "можжевельник" при том, что bor - 'сосна'). Этимология же первой части сложного слова остается затемненной. При наличии обл. *можжуха* П.Я.Черных считает естественным связать его с диал. *мзга* (*мозга) [<*мъгга 'гниль'; ср.: *мОзгнуть* - 'преть', 'гнить', 'чахнуть'; *мОзглый* - 'затхлый', 'гнилой', 'кислый'; *мзга* - 'ситник' (растение Juncus), а также 'гриб-моховик']. Любопытно, что и первая часть латинского названия можжевельника (juni-perus) тоже связана с растением juncus - 'ситник'. Может быть, растение получило свое название по горькому вкусу ягод? Есть также вероятность, что слово восходит не к **можжевель*, а к** мозжель*, где -ель является суффиксом. Дальнейшие рассуждения не приводятся.

Фасмер отмечает, что версия о том, что **можжевельник** происходит от первонач. знач. "чахлый ельник" (а именно такая версия предстает перед нами из рассуждений П.Я.Черных), невероятна :-))

Как видите, версий предостаточно, но четкий ответ на вопрос о происхождении слова **можжевельник** дать трудно.

Comment: Фасмер, похоже, сам крепко путается, но - в частностях, все-таки родство с мозг (древесиной) наиболее вероятно. Остальное - просто фантастично, особенно про ельник.

Answer (score 1):

Если принять версию Фасмера о родсвенности можжевельника с "мозг", то и с "размозжить" эти слова родсвенны. 
"Мозжить" тоже восходит к "мозг", первоначально "разможить" означало расколоть, разбить что-то с целью достать мозг (изгначально - мягкую древесину).
Разумеется, никак нельзя утверждать, что одно слово происходит от другого, это, так сказать, дальние родственники.

Comment: На Фасмера полностью полагаться, как уже несколько раз выяснялось, тоже не следует, хоть его словарь и считается авторитетным :-)) Беда в том, что с ним никто пока по охвату материала тягаться не может :-)) А Викисловарю я бы тоже не доверяла, особенно в том случае, когда нет ссылки ни на какой авторитетный источник.

Comment: Ну так и я о том же. Но тут-то, если отбросить детали, основной тезис о родстве с "мозгом" можно принять.     
На Вики я в подобных случаях тоже никогда не ссылаюсь.  
Тем более, когда даже своим серым умом можно заподозрить неладное.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно наиболее распространённой этимологии, можжевельник восходит к праславянскому *moždževelь, которое, в свою очередь, восходит к праиндоевропейскому корню* mezg- «плести, вязать».

Comment: Интуитивно версия кажется неправдоподобной. Кроме Вики и копипастов с неё никто подобной версии не приводит. Я не знаю, возможет ли переход moždž<mezg (с этим надо серьёзно разбираться), но вот суффикс "-евель" в праславянском совершенно непонятен. Даже если допустить что там на самом деле приятяжательной "авъль" (в журавль), что могло бы значить это moždževelь? "Принадлежащий узлу"?